# How does this aggregated query find the correct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble understanding this code. It actually seems to work, but I don't understand how the correct value for activity year and month is "found" get the proper min and max? Or is it running all permutations getting the highest? This is very strange to me.

I do understand how the dateadd works, just not how the query is actually working on the whole. This may be a bad question since I don't actually need help solving a problem, just insight into why this works.

```
select 
    EmployeeNumber,
    sum(BaseCalculation) as BaseCalculation,
    min(dateadd(mm, (ActivityYear - 1900) * 12 + ActivityMonth - 1 , 0)) as StartDate,
    max(dateadd(mm, (ActivityYear - 1900) * 12 + ActivityMonth - 1 , 0)) as EndDate
from 
    Compensation 
where 
    1=1
    -- and
group by 
    EmployeeNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for both the `min` and `max` function call, the algorithm is

```
dateadd(mm, (ActivityYear - 1900) * 12 + ActivityMonth - 1 , 0)
```

Your query compute all possible date from the `Compensation` table using this algorithm. Then, you select the minimum date as `StartDate` and the maximum as `EndDate`.

This is how the proper max and min are returned.

Note that the dateadd signature is `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`

Since the last parameter is 0, you are addind to month(mm) the number calculated in the algorithm, and return the corresponding date starting from 0.

Check this out for more information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is converting the columns `ActivityYear` and `ActivityMmonth` to a date.  It is doing so by counting the number of months since 1900 and adding them to time zero.  So, Jan 2000 would become something like Jan, 100.  This seems like a very arcane calculation, because dates that are about 2,000 years old are not really useful.

Of course, this assumes that `ActivityYear` is a recognizable recent year.

I would convert the year and month to the first day of the beginning of the month, with something like this:

```
min(cast(cast(ActivityYear * 10000 + ActivityMonth + 1 as varchar(255)) as date)
```

Comment: I understand how the dateadd function works, just not sure how the aggregation is actually working -- I did not expect this code to work to correctly get the min and the max. I'll clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server will calculate every value of that statement, and then only return the min and max.

Although I cannot say for sure that sql server executes this way internally, the way I think about it I imagine that the engine strips off the group by and all the aggregate functions, runs that query. And then just sums/finds the min etc off of that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did not understand that it would run that min/max along all of the permutations in the result set. This is very handy. If I could I would upvote this comment.